# Could not find the main class, but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have a very simple project with just one class in Eclipse, which runs without problems.
When I run it through the console with java Monitor I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Monitor
```

Same with the exported jar files.
Thanks

Classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-net-3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/fluent-hc-4.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpclient-4.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpclient-cache-4.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpclient-win-4.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpmime-4.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javax.mail.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jna-4.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/twilio-java-sdk-4.4.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: _When I run it through the console_ how you run it? Show the commands.

Comment: cd into the src folder, java Monitor, I also tried to move it into a package and then java pack.Monitor

Comment: No, it runs in eclipse without any problem

Comment: Did you compile your code first? `javac` is the command that is used for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was that the JRE and JDK had different versions, JDK was 1.8 and run in Eclipse, 1.6 was the JRE which was used with the jar/console